# Saxon bug reappearing in Saxon-HE-9.6.0-5.jar

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I am seeing this bug:
https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2160

appearing in Saxon-HE-9.6.0-5.jar. From the link it was fixed in 9.6.0.2. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error evaluating template  at line 1 in module 

at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:349)

at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1124)

at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2106)

at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1705)

at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:547)

at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:179)
```

I haven't been able to narrown down which XSLT is at the root of this. I will post when I have more information.

Comment: It could well be a different bug with the same symptoms. We can't do anything to help without a repro, I'm afraid. When you are able to reproduce it, please post a bug directly at saxonica.plan.io so we don't have to track it in two separate places.

Comment: Opened https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2415